# Meaning of the second bracket [] in the print statement in python

Tags: python, string, formatting, slice, reverse

Below is the code.
I don't understand the meaning of the last bracket in [::-1][:-1], and how come can you write two brackets at the same time. I understand that the first slice bracket reverses the order of the string, but what does the second do?

```
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    temp = list(alphabets[:n][i-1:])
    print('-'.join(temp[::-1][:-1]+temp).center(4*n-3,'-'))
```

Thanks for cooperation!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation). You can chain slices as much as you want--they are processed left to right with results being passed from each slice to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question I will use an example:

`list = [1,2,3,4,5]`

As you said, the first brackets will reverse your list.
Then, you will get as a result: `[5,4,3,2,1]`

On that list you will do the slicing: `[:-1]`. That will give you as a result `[5,4,3,2]`.

The brackets meaning is the same:
`[<startIndex>:<endIndex>:<how to go through>]`

For more information about the `<how to go through>` part, please read here: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/